# BeanCreationException: Requested bean is currently in creation

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have searched a few posts, but have not found any suitable answer for the exception `BeanCurrentlyInCreationException`.  I attempted to use `@Lazy` and `@Bean` while creating the `TaskScheduler`, but neither approach proved to be helpful.

###### MyDireConfig.java

```java
@Slf4j
@Configuration
public class MyDireConfig implements InitializingBean {
    
       
    @Value("${testdir.retain-backup-files:true}")
    boolean retainBackupFiles;
    @Value("${testdir.backup-directory}")
    String backupDirectory;
    @Value("${testdir.error-directory}")
    String errorDirectory;
    
    @Value("${camel.springboot.auto-startup:true}")
    String camelSpringbootAutoStartup;
    @Value("${camel.springboot.main-run-controller:true}")
    String camelSpringbootMainRunController;
    
    @Autowired (required=false)
    MyDireCleaner myDireCleaner;
    
    @Override
    public void afterPropertiesSet() throws Exception {
        if (cleanInterval < 300000L) cleanInterval = 300000L;
        if (retainBackupFiles && maxBackupFileAge > 0) {
            log.info("Max backup file age: " + maxBackupFileAge + " day(s)");
            Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
            c.add(Calendar.DATE, -maxBackupFileAge);
            taskScheduler().scheduleWithFixedDelay(()->{myDireCleaner.deleteExpiredPaths(Paths.get(backupDirectory), c.getTime());}, new Date(System.currentTimeMillis() + 10000L), cleanInterval);
        } 
    }

    public boolean retainBackupFiles() {
        return retainBackupFiles;
    }
    
    public String getBackupDirectory(String dirId) {
        return Paths.get(backupDirectory, dirId).toString().replace("\\", "/");
    }
    
    public String getErrorDirectory(String dirId) {
        return Paths.get(errorDirectory, dirId).toString().replace("\\", "/");
    }
    
    
    @Bean
    public TaskScheduler taskScheduler() {
        return new ConcurrentTaskScheduler();
    }
}
```

Error log:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException:
Error creating bean with name 'MyDireConfig' defined in URL
[jar:file:/C:/Program%20Files/test/myprogram/lib/myapp.jar!/BOOT-INF/classes!/com/test/myprogram/MyDireConfig.class]:
Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCurrentlyInCreationException:
Error creating bean with name 'MyDireConfig': *Requested bean is
currently in creation: Is there an unresolvable circular reference?*
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1804)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:620)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:542)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:955)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:918)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have separated the Bean creation to a separate configuration class as follows, and it worked.

**TaskSchedulerBean.java**

```
@Configuration
public class TaskSchedulerBean {
    @Bean
    public TaskScheduler taskScheduler() {
        return new ConcurrentTaskScheduler();
    }
}
```

**MyDireConfig.java**

```
@Slf4j
@Configuration
public class MyDireConfig implements InitializingBean {
    

    
    @Value("${testdir.retain-backup-files:true}")
    boolean retainBackupFiles;
    @Value("${testdir.backup-directory}")
    String backupDirectory;
    @Value("${testdir.error-directory}")
    String errorDirectory;
    
    @Value("${camel.springboot.auto-startup:true}")
    String camelSpringbootAutoStartup;
    @Value("${camel.springboot.main-run-controller:true}")
    String camelSpringbootMainRunController;
    
    @Autowired (required=false)
    MyDireCleaner myDireCleaner;
    
    @Autowired
    TaskSchedulerBean taskSchedulerBean;
    
    @Override
    public void afterPropertiesSet() throws Exception {
        if (cleanInterval < 300000L) cleanInterval = 300000L;
        if (retainBackupFiles && maxBackupFileAge > 0) {
            log.info("Max backup file age: " + maxBackupFileAge + " day(s)");
            Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
            c.add(Calendar.DATE, -maxBackupFileAge);
            taskSchedulerBean.taskScheduler().scheduleWithFixedDelay(()->{myDireCleaner.deleteExpiredPaths(Paths.get(backupDirectory), c.getTime());}, new Date(System.currentTimeMillis() + 10000L), cleanInterval);
        } 
    }

    public boolean retainBackupFiles() {
        return retainBackupFiles;
    }
    
    public String getBackupDirectory(String dirId) {
        return Paths.get(backupDirectory, dirId).toString().replace("\\", "/");
    }
    
    public String getErrorDirectory(String dirId) {
        return Paths.get(errorDirectory, dirId).toString().replace("\\", "/");
    }   
}
```